# Need a sequelize alternative to a find raw query

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

`SELECT * FROM recommended_plan WHERE user_id = ? AND created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM recommended_plan WHERE user_id = ?)`

I am stuck at converting this raw query into a sequelize one.

Answer (score 0):

CASE 1 - you have only one record with max created_at value
First you can convert it to this equivalent one:

```sql
SELECT * FROM recommended_plan WHERE user_id = ?
order by created_at desc
limit 1
```

(Please pay attention that the `limit` option depends on a certain DBMS and could have a different name and/or syntax).
Now you can easily construct the corresponding Sequelize query:

```js
const plan = await RecommendedPlan.findAll({
  where: {
    user_id: userId
  },
  limit: 1,
  order: [['created_at', 'desc']]
})
```

CASE 2 - you have several records with max created_at value:
You can use `Sequelize.literal` to use a condition with a subquery:

```js
const plan = await RecommendedPlan.findAll({
  where: {
      user_id: userId,
      created_at: Sequelize.literal('(SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM recommended_plan rp WHERE rp.user_id = $userId)')
  },
  bind: {
    userId: userId
  }
})
```

Comment: Actually, there are multiple rows with a same created_at date and I have to find them all.

Comment: Please look at the edited answer